# c# combine yield return of multiple functions

Tags: c#, return, ienumerable, concatenation, yield

c# yield compute will delay execution of each iteration of a loop only when that  particular enumerated element is actually needed by the caller. Is it possible to combine multiple such yield return functions and still expose a dynamically enumerated set to the ultimate caller ?

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetDelayedCompute1()
{
    // compute ...
    foreach(var s in results)
    {
        yield return s;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetDelayedCompute2()
{
    // compute ... 
    foreach(var s in results)
    {
        yield return s;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetResults()
{
    // how to combine results of GetDelayedCompute1 and GetDelayedCompute2
    // and yield return without forcing enumeration
}
```

Comment: It's nothing to do with `yield` - so long as your method returns an `IEnumerable<string>` and nothing in the method forces iteration then you get the same result. You could do `public IEnumerable<string> GetDelayedCompute1() => result.Select(s => s);` and get lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 10):

The results of a LINQ operation are lazy-evaluated, so you can just:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetResults()
{
    return GetDelayedCompute1().Concat(GetDelayedCompute2());
}
```

The results are not actually materialized until you enumerate the result of `GetResults()`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to combine multiple such yield return functions

Yes, just continue the mechanism of `yield returns` by `foreach`ing  over each of the methods.

```
foreach (var str in GetDelayedCompute1())
    yield return str;

foreach (var str in GetDelayedCompute2())
    yield return str;
```

---

Otherwise `Union` the result and return

```
 return GetDelayedCompute1().Union(GetDelayedCompute2());
```

Answer (score 0):

In .Net4.8 Concat is much slower than yield return via foreach.
I made a little benchmark test with BenchmarkDotNet of the following test functions:

```
public IEnumerable<int> YieldReturn()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        foreach (var inner in this.Forward())
        {
            yield return inner;
        }

        foreach (var inner in this.Backward())
        {
            yield return inner;
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerable<int> Concat()
{
    var result = Enumerable.Empty<int>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        result = result.Concat(Forward());
        result = result.Concat(Backward());
    }

    return result;
}

public IEnumerable<int> Forward()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<int> Backward()
{
    for (var i = 1000; i > 0; i--)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

Then I let it ran with .Net4.8 and .Net5.0.
This are the results:

| Method | Job | Runtime | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YieldReturn | Job-IOETON | .NET 5.0 | 2.668 ms | 0.0720 ms | 0.0428 ms | 1.00 | 0.00 | 496.0938 | 496.0938 | 496.0938 | 2 MB |
| YieldReturn | Job-BBBSSF | .NET Framework 4.8 | 2.854 ms | 0.0997 ms | 0.0659 ms | 1.06 | 0.03 | 695.3125 | 667.9688 | 667.9688 | 3 MB |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Concat | Job-IOETON | .NET 5.0 | 1.922 ms | 0.0388 ms | 0.0257 ms | 1.00 | 0.00 | 496.0938 | 496.0938 | 496.0938 | 2 MB |
| Concat | Job-BBBSSF | .NET Framework 4.8 | 124.980 ms | 4.6759 ms | 3.0928 ms | 65.03 | 1.81 | 600.0000 | 600.0000 | 600.0000 | 3 MB |

In the column "Mean" you can see the duration of the functions.
So in .Net4.8 and bellow I would use the yield return solution.